# Keep MPMoviePlayerViewController playing when in background

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to playback videos in my iOS app on iPhone4 (iOS5.1), new iPad (iOS5.1), iPad (iOS4.2).

I press home button twice when playing a video, the multitask dock shows and player pauses.

I have tried to call player's `play` method in appDelegate `applicationWillResignActive`,but it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do to avoid player pause ?

Another question, how to show video's title on remote control panel? (swipe multitask dock to leftmost).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you shouldn't continue playing the video. According to Apple App Programming Guide, you are supposed to pause visual activity in the application when that happens. I am not 100% sure if the App Store submission will accept that behavior.

You can show the video title by providing metadata to the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`:

[See Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

As written there:

> The system displays now-playing information on the device lock screen and in the multimedia controls in the multitasking UI.

Comment: The argument given here goes against music/similar apps that are already on the App Store and the idea of multitasking in general. It's also possible to use the multitasking controls to manually press 'play' after closing an app with a movie playing, so why shouldn't it be possible to have it continue playing?

Comment: Music is not a visual activity. When an application goes in this mode, it would be distracting for the application to continue animating/playing a visual cue/video, etc. I believe Apple would have given this common use case a thought. Again, this is my personal opinion. I have updated my answer that changes 'pause everything' to 'pause visual activity'.